# Segment in Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $x,y \in X$. We define segment between $x$ and $y$ by $$\left [ x,y \right ] = \left \{ z \in X : \left \| x - z\right \| + \left \| z - y\right \|=\left \| x - y\right \|\right \}.$$ Show that this segment has the following representation $$\left [ x,y \right ] = \left \{ \lambda x + \left ( 1- \lambda \right ) y | \lambda \in \left [ 0,1 \right ] \right \}$$

---

I proved $\left [ x,y \right ] \supset \left \{ \lambda x + \left ( 1- \lambda \right ) y | \lambda \in \left [ 0,1 \right ] \right \}$ but cannot do in converse case. For $z \in \left [ x,y \right ]$ we have $\left \| x - z\right \| = \lambda \left \| x - y\right \|$ and $\left \| z - y\right \| = \left ( 1 -\lambda \right ) \left \| x - y\right \|$. I don't know how to keep on.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is not true. Let $X$ be $R^2$  and $u,v$ a basis of $X$, endows $X$ with the norm sup in the basis $u,v$: $\|xu+yv\|=sup(\mid x\mid,\mid y\mid)$ consider $c=5u, d=10u$ $\| 10u-5u\|=5$. Let $z=8u+1v$, $\| z-c\|=3$ $\| z-d\|=2$, 2+3=5

Answer (score 2):

It is not true, take $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the $l_1$ norm.

Let $x=e_1,y=e_2$, and $z=0$. Then $\|x-y\| = 2$, $\|x-z\| = 1, \|z-y\| =1$, but clearly $0$ is not on the line through $x,y$.